# Laravel Livewire data table sorting livewire update payload

Tags: laravel, sorting, datatable, laravel-livewire

my laravel livewire 3 app has a datatable. Sorting this table triggers the livewire update which is huge in size for a relatively small table of just 10 rows and 7 columns. The queries are all lighnting fast already.

How can I make the actual sorting of the table snappy? I believe that I have to tell livewire which parts of the page it needs to reload/reender via wire:target.

However I can't find any resources on how to do this without breaking the site.

Another possibility would be to use a local html5 DB, do the client-side sorting there and then sync back with the mysql DB in the background.

The tables need to be synchronized because I trigger action when clicking specific row in the table.

What would be the best approach to improve sorting speed? Pagination can be used but not for just 10 rows.

Comment: It's really difficult to say why it's slow without seeing your actual code and with more information. The Livewire update request on its own isn't very resource intensive, so I highly doubt it's caused from part of the Livewire framework.